# Google Universal Analytics Simple Product Price Zero when Configurable Product Sold Magento 1.4.2

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product

I have two issues with Universal Analytics tracking product prices:

1. When a Configurable Product without any custom options is sold, Google Universal Analytics tracks the sale of the associated Simple Product, but the price of the Simple Product is missing.  Therefore I cannot report on the total sales of these items.
2. When a Configurable Product with a custom option is sold, Google Universal Analytics tracks the sale of the both the Configurable product with correct price AND the associated Simple Product with price missing.  So I can report on the correct total sales amount of these items, but not the quantities.

Here is the current code in our checkout that Google support provided for Universal Analytics:

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId()); 
$subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
$order_id = $order->getIncrementId(); //the id of the order
//$order->getIncrementId();//the increment id of the order
$gtotal = $order->getBaseGrandTotal(); //grand total of the order
$tax = $order->getBaseTaxAmount(); //tax amount of the order
$shipping = $order->getBaseShippingAmount(); //shipping amount of the order
$address = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
$city = $address['city'];
$state = $address['region'];
$country = $address['country_id'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': '',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '<?php echo $gtotal;?>',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '<?php echo $shipping;?>',  // Shipping.
  'tax': '<?php echo $tax;?>' // Tax.
});

<?php 
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount=count($items);
$name=array();
$unitPrice=array();
$sku=array();
$ids=array();
$qty=array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{?>

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': '<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': '<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>',                 // SKU code.
  'category': '',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '<?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?>',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '<?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); ?>'                   // Quantity.
});
<?php 
}
?> 

ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

I wish to only get the Simple Product details and correct price, and not Configurable details or price.  So I will need a check to see if it's a configurable product to then only get the associated Simple Product details.

I don't know whether it should be parent and child, of test for configurable first.  It will be a change to the code below but I don't have the knowledge to figure this out!

Many thanks in advance :)

```
<?php 
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount=count($items);
$name=array();
$unitPrice=array();
$sku=array();
$ids=array();
$qty=array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Skip if the item itself not parent :

```
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
    {
        if($item->getParentItemId()){
            continue;           
        }       
    ?>

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': '<?php echo $item->getName(); ?>',    // Product name. Required.
      'sku': '<?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>',                 // SKU code.
      'category': '',         // Category or variation.
      'price': '<?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?>',                 // Unit price.
      'quantity': '<?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); ?>'                   // Quantity.
    });
    <?php 
}
?>
```